# unable to start MongoDB server

Tags: mongodb, server, service, ubuntu-20.04, wsl-2

I installed MongoDB in wsl using the official windows document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-database).
I have created a path and can start the a DB instance using

```
sudo mongod --dbpath ~/data/db
```

but after following the docs further and adding the init script [from here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/debian/init.d) to start MongoDB as a service, and running this command

```
sudo service mongodb start
```

returns output:

```
* Starting database mongod                                                                                                             [fail]
```

and as expected when I run,

```
sudo service mongodb status
```

I have the output

```
* Checking status of database mongod                                                                                                          
* apparently not running
                                                                                                                                   [fail]
```

now, how do I solve this?

Comment: Is that the full output in the console of your `service start` command? Is there anything in the `mongod` log file when you try this?

Comment: oh yes I didn't see the log

Comment: Running `sudo mongod ...` and `sudo service mongodb start` basially starts the mongod twice, which is not possible.

Comment: Did you check the logfile? Typically at `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`

Comment: I have share the log @WernfriedDomscheit

Comment: {"t":{"$date":"2022-10-18T15:09:19.166+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23330,   "ctx":"main","msg":"ERROR: Cannot write pid file to {path_string}: {errAndStr_second}","attr":{"path_string":"/var/run/mongod.pid","errAndStr_second":"Permission denied"}} 
This seems to be the error

Comment: Maybe you should better follow the official documentation: [Install MongoDB Community Edition on Ubuntu](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same error.

I think owner for this file was root.

when I checked `ls -l` inside `/var/run` directory
I got this

```
drwxrwxrwt 2 root    root     40 Jan  2 19:53 lock
drwxr-xr-x 2 mongodb mongodb  60 Jan  2 20:16 mongodb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root     6 Jan  2 20:35 mongod.pid
drwxr-xr-x 2 root    root     40 Jan  2 20:00 needrestart
drwxrwxrwt 2 root    root     40 Jan  2 19:53 shm
drwx--x--x 3 root    root     60 Jan  2 19:53 sudo
drwxr-xr-x 2 root    root     40 Jan  2 19:53 user
drwxr-xr-x 2 root    root    140 Jan  2 20:19 WSL
```

`sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /var/run/mongod.pid`

after running this issue was resolved

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you do something like this

wget -qO - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mongodb/mongo/master/debian/init.d > /etc/init.d/mongod && chmod +x /etc/init.d/mongod

I had this problem to. At the time of writing the HEAD of that file seems broken. You can try:

wget -qO - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mongodb/mongo/cad54eb5ebdff24ecec53b56788cd151d8d64272/debian/init.d  > /etc/init.d/mongod && chmod +x /etc/init.d/mongod

to get the previous version